# How to get default selected value into javascript and pass it to php on page load?

Tags: javascript, php, html

Here I am trying to select Grade from dropdown list and display Value an output. That is working fine only manually selection of Grade after page loaded.

1. I want to get by default selected Grade value output when page get loaded first time. As in this form A Grade selected and its output should display.

I try to get this value by using onload="get_value()" function in html body tag which works for default selected Grade value, but it is continuously loading and loading, unable to select another option.

2. Also only selected Grade option should be display in drop down as it is showing only default selected option every time.

Please guide me suitable solution.

thanks

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['grade']))
{
$rest_grade= $_GET['grade'];
echo $rest_grade;
}
else
{
$rest_grade="A";
echo $rest_grade;
}
?>
<html><head>
<script>
function get_value()
{   
var get_grade = document.getElementById("grade_id").value;  
var url ="?grade="+get_grade;
window.location = url;      
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form action="" method="post">
<label>Grade</label>
    <select name="grade" id="grade_id" onchange="get_value(this.value)">
        <option id="1" value="A" selected>A Grade</option>
        <option id="2" value="B" >B Grade</option>
        <option id="3" value="C" >C Grade</option>
        <option id="4" value="D" >D Grade</option>
    </select>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this one:

```
<select name="grade" id="grade_id" onchange="get_value(this.value)">
    <option id="1" <?php if($rest_grade == 'A') { echo 'selected="selected"';}?> value="A" selected>A Grade</option>
    <option id="2" <?php if($rest_grade == 'B') { echo 'selected="selected"';}?>  value="B" >B Grade</option>
    <option id="3" <?php if($rest_grade == 'C') { echo 'selected="selected"';}?>  value="C" >C Grade</option>
    <option id="4" <?php if($rest_grade == 'D') { echo 'selected="selected"';}?>  value="D" >D Grade</option>
</select>
```

You can also make it simpler like:

```
<select name="grade" id="grade_id" onchange="javascript:location.href='page.php?grade='+this.value">
        <?php 
            $rest_grade = (isset($_GET['grade']) && $_GET['grade'] != NULL) ? $_GET['grade'] : 'A';
            $id = 1;
            foreach (range('A', 'D') as $char) {
                $selected = ($char == $rest_grade) ? 'selected="selected"' : "";
                echo '<option id="'.$id.'" value="'.$char.'" '.$selected.'>'.$char.' Grade</option>';
                $id++;
            }
       ?>
</select>
```

Comment: Manish Jangir: your code is good and working fine when page get loaded and a option is selected from dropdown option. Same thing is working fine with my code too. My query is can we get the initial selected value defined in select option form on page's first time loading. As i define selected as <option id="1" value="A" selected>A Grade</option>

Comment: Manish Jangir: It should display value A on page load. that is my concern. I am getting value A only via using <body onload="get_value()">, but in this case unable to select other option from dropdown list.

Comment: Manish Jangir: thanks for update, i also updated similar thing in my code.

Answer (score 1):

This will be helpful to you.
Before using this coding you will need to fetch all the data by using select query.
After fetching the data you can use this code

```
<?php
    $select_A = '';
    $select_B = '';
    $select_C = '';
    $select_D = '';

    if($rest_grade == 'A'):
        $select_A = 'selected="selected"';
    elseif($rest_grade == 'B'):
        $select_B = 'selected="selected"';
    elseif($rest_grade == 'C'):
        $select_C = 'selected="selected"';
    elseif($rest_grade == 'D'):
        $select_D = 'selected="selected"';
    endif;
?>
<form action="" method="post">
<label>Grade</label>
    <select name="grade" id="grade_id" onchange="get_value(this.value)">
        <option id="1" <?php echo $select_A; ?> value="A" selected>A Grade</option>
        <option id="2" <?php echo $select_B; ?>  value="B" >B Grade</option>
        <option id="3" <?php echo $select_C; ?>  value="C" >C Grade</option>
        <option id="4" <?php echo $select_D; ?>  value="D" >D Grade</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

Comment: Nikunj:your code is good and working fine when page get loaded and a option is selected from dropdown option. Same thing is working fine with my code too. My query is can we get the initial selected value defined in select option form on page's first time loading. As i define selected as <option id="1" value="A" selected>A Grade</option>

Comment: Nikunj:It should display value A on page load.